# Howto read this large text file? Memory Mapped File?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, file-io

I am in the design phase of a simple tool I want to write where I need to read large log files. To give you guys some context I will first explain you something about it.

The log files I need to read consists of log entries which always consist of the following 3-line format:

```
statistics : <some data which is more of less of the same length about 100 chars>
request :  <some xml string which can be small (10KB) or big (25MB) and anything in between>
response :  <ditto>
```

The log files can be about 100-600MB of size which means a lot of log entries. Now these log entries can have a relation with each other, for this I need to start reading the file from the end to the beginning. These relationship can be deduced from the statistics line.

I want to use the info in the statistics line to build up some datagrid which the users can use to search through the data and do some filtering operations. Now I don't want to load the request / response lines into memory until the user actually needs it. In addition I want to keep the memory load small by limiting the maximum of loaded request/response entries.

So I think I need to save the offsets of the statistics line when I am parsing the file for the first time and creating a index of statistics. Then when the user clicks on some statistic which is a element of a log entry then I read the request / response from the file by using this offset. I can then hold it some memory pool which takes care that there are not to much loaded request / response entries (see earlier req).

The problem is that I don't know how often the user is going to need the request/response data. It could be a lot it could be a few times. In addition the log file could be loaded from a network share.

The question I have is:

1. Is this a scenario when you should use a memory mapped file because of the fact there could be a lot of read operations? Or is it better to use a plain filestream. BTW. I don't need write operations to the log file at this stage but it could be in the future!

If you have other tips or see flaws in my thinking so far please let me know as well. I am open for any approach.

**Update:**

To clarify some more:

- The tool itself has to do the parsing when the user loads a log file from a drive or network share.
- The tool will be written as WinForms application.
- The user can export a made selection of log entries. At this moment the format of this export is unknown (binary, file db, textfile). This export can be imported by the application itself which then only shows the selection made by the user.

Comment: Side note: You really need to think about what your goals are... As of now your question is "I don't know what I want but is it fast enough?" Since you tagged it with "performance" you should have some sort of numbers in mind. I.e. if "keep the memory load small" is the only goal - reading only one record at a time and even sequentially seeking through whole file is perfectly ok... You will not be able to optimize anything till you get reasonable requirements - "need...data.. a lot it could be a few times" require pretty much opposite optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about some stored data that has some defined relationships between actual entries... Maybe it's just me, but this scenario just calls for some kind of a relational database. I'd suggest to consider some portable db, like SQL Server CE for instance. It'll make your life much easier and provide exactly the functionality you need. If you use db instead, you can query exactly the data you need, without ever needing to handle large files like this.

Comment: I have been thinking about this as well and maybe it's just the better option but I am not convinced yet. In this scenario I need to parse the whole file which is the thing that wories and got me started thinking in a different solution but maybe I am wrong. The only downside would be that the initial parsing time would be longer and maybe unnecessary (most of the time the user is only looking for some specific entries). A part of my question still stands about howto read the textfile. I will keep my question open for now and maybe mark this as answer later. +1 for now.

Comment: I decided to go for the db option because indexing the byte offsets for the request / response lines requires me to read the whole line anyway. This is because they have a variable length. In order to do this I will have to create my own streamreader which doesn't bring enough benefits to justify it. If I go for the db option I can simply use the StreamReader. BTW I do have to check how SQL Server compact handles it memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending the request/response chunk over the network, the network send() time is likely to be so much greater than the difference between seek()/read() and using memmap that it won't matter.  To really make this scale, a simple solution is to just breakup the file into many files, one for each chunk you want to serve (since the "request" can be up to 25 MB).  Then your HTTP server will send that chunk as effeciently as possible (perhaps even using zerocopy, depending on your webserver).  If you have many small "request" chunks, and only a few giant ones, you could break-out only the ones past a certain threshold.

Comment: I don't know why I assumed you would be sending this over a network ..  But I'll leave my answer anyway.  Blam has a good point tho; unless you've seen that seek()/read() is actually a performance problem, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're not wrong, the log file could be loaded from a network share if the user choose to do so. That said I am not in control of the process that generates the log and serves the log. So this is not really a option for me. But I understand that using a memmap file doesn't have benefits when the log file is loaded from a network share? +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't disagree with with answer from walther.  I would go db or all memory.

Why are you so concerned about saving memory as 600 MB is not that much.  Are you going to be running on machines with less than 2 GB of memory?

Load into a dictionary with statistics as a key and the value a class with two properties - request and response.   Dictionary is fast.  LINQ is powerful and fast.

Comment: Yes the machines where it will be running on have 2GB-3GB of memory. As of now the machines are already running low on memory because of all the other programs the machines are running. There is no budget for new machines. From your answer I understand you wouldn't use the mepmap scenario but a filestream?

Comment: I just don't get coding around less than a 1 GB footprint when I feel it is the appropriate architecture.  You asked if anyone saw a flaw in your thinking.  And there you have it.  I think that is a flaw in you thinking.

Comment: Wanting to be efficient is not a flaw in my thinking, it's one of the requirements for the architecture. But still thanks for your answer.

Comment: Cool. Efficient can be a lot of things.  Ease of coding, memory, cpu, io, and execution times.  If your design parameter was smallest memory footprint then that was no clear to me.